# APK based vs. service based plugins

Tags: android, plugins

I am looking now into re-architecting a library based Android App, so that instead of providing each library's functionality at build time (limiting its expansion to me only), I would just provide a base App and an SDK that would allow any developer to independently write a plugin.

I couldn't find many ways of accomplishing this on Android (unlike .NET's Unity dependency injection framework which supports independent DLLs). What I found was:

1. APK based approach: 
   http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/05/31/android-plugin-application.aspx
2. Service based approach:
   http://androidsrc.net/creating-android-app-plugin-architecture-tutorial/

My question is: Are there additional ways of accomplishing this? (note: ways that are **legal** from Google Play's ToS)

Also, in your opinion, which of the two approaches that I listed above is superior?

Comment: 1 and 2 are inseparable, insofar as you cannot have a service without an APK. Any of the IPC options (activities, services, receivers, providers) can form part of a plugin system.

Comment: Thanks, but why the downvote? Isn't this a place where the clueless can ask questions demonstrating some ignorance. :)   Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: "but why the downvote?" -- I did not downvote the question. If I had to guess, it is because you referenced the Play Store's ToS, and [questions about app distribution channels are considered to be off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). Also, "superior" implies seeking opinions, and that too is considered to be off-topic.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for explaining. I was not aware of the SO rules you described, so from now on I will be careful not to repeat those mistakes,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if an app will accept some sort of plugins from other developers, those plugins are distributed in the form of APK files, whether through the Play Store or through some other channel. Those plugins may need different permissions than yours, for example, and that can only be accomplished if they are first-class citizens on the Android device.

Hence, a plugin is merely some other app that interacts with yours through some documented and supported IPC mechanism. The big four Android components — activities, services, receivers, and providers — are all possibly relevant for a plugin. It really depends on what you want the plugin to do and what the plugin needs from your app to be able to do it. In the abstract, we cannot tell you which of those to use.

Personally, if I were going to do this sort of thing, I would write the base app plus at least three plugins. The act of "eating your own dog food" when writing those plugins will help guide you towards what IPC mechanisms are needed. Even if, in the end, you ship the plugins' functionality directly baked into the main app, having "real" plugins will help shape your SDK, your security model, etc.